# Multiple variadic templates function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Assume I have two functions `f1()` and `f2()` defined as follow:

```
template<class ... Types> void f1(Types ... args1)
template<class ... Types> void f2(Types ... args2)
```

Now I want to create a third function `f3()` which takes input `f1()` and `f2()`, how do I define `f3()` with both `args1...` and `args2...`?

```
template<class F1, class F2> void f3(F1 f1, F2 f2) {
  f1();  // how do I call f1? I need to pass in the args... 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your expected behavior?  And it's confusing that you use the names `f1` and `f2` in two ways - do you want `f3` to call the function passed to it, or the function actually named `f1` declared above?  How are these two things related?

Comment: @aschepler what max66 added answers my question well. I have two functions: f1 and f2, both are variadic templates functions. Now I want to pass them to a new function, f3. At the same time, I need to pass the params for f1 and f2 to f3 as well. If f1 and f2 share the same params, it's easy. But for my case they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Because a template functions are set of functions. And you can pass a functions, explicating the template types,

```
f3(f1<int, long, long>, f2<char, int>);
```

and not the full set of functions.

The best I can suggest is to wrap your template functions in structs

```
struct s1
 {
   template <typename ... Types>
   static void f1 (Types ... args1)
    { }
 };

struct s2
 {
   template <typename ... Types>
   static void f2 (Types ... args2)
    { }
 };
```

so you can pass to `f3()` `s1` and `s2` objects

```
s1  a;
s2  b;

f3(a, b);
```

or simply the types

```
f3<s1, s2>();
```

As suggested by Jarod42, you can also wrap `f1()` and `f2()` inside a couple of lambdas (only from C++14)

```
auto l1 = [](auto&& ... args) { f1(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
auto l2 = [](auto&& ... args) { f2(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

f3(l1, l2)
```

> what I mean is when I call f3, I offer f1 and f2. I also need to pass in the params for f1 and f2. How do I do that?

But the argument for `f1()` and `f2()` are the same? 
Or are two different sets?

In the first case, you can pass they as template variadic arguments; something as (following the Jarod42's suggestion)

```
template <typename L1, typename L2, typename ... Args>
void f3 (L1 l1, L2 l2, Args const & ... as)
 {
   L1(as...);
   L2(as...);
 }  

auto l1 = [](auto&& ... args) { f1(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
auto l2 = [](auto&& ... args) { f2(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

f3(l1, l2, 1, '2', 3L, 4ULL);
```

If you need two different set of argument, you need to wrap the arguments in `std::tuple`'s or something similar.

```
template <typename L1, typename L2, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
void f3 (L1 l1, L2 l2, std::tuple<As1...> const & t1, std::tuple<As2...> const & t2)
 {
   std::apply(l1, t1);
   std::apply(l2, t2);
 }  

auto l1 = [](auto&& ... args) { f1(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
auto l2 = [](auto&& ... args) { f2(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

f3(l1, l2, std::make_tuple(1, 2l, '3'), std::make_tuple('4', 5ull));
```

But take in count that `std::apply()` is available only from C++17: before is a little more complicated extract the arguments from the tuples.

> how do I do that without c++17?

The following is a full C++14 example that unpack tuples using `std::index_sequence_for` and `std::index_sequence`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts>
void f1 (Ts ... as)
 { std::cout << "- f1: " << sizeof...(Ts) << " arguments" << std::endl; }

template <typename ... Ts>
void f2 (Ts ... as)
 { std::cout << "- f2: " << sizeof...(Ts) << " arguments" << std::endl; }

template <typename L, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void f3_helper (L l, std::tuple<Ts...> const & t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 { l(std::get<Is>(t)...); }

template <typename L1, typename L2, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
void f3 (L1 l1, L2 l2, std::tuple<As1...> const & t1,
         std::tuple<As2...> const & t2)
 {
   f3_helper(l1, t1, std::index_sequence_for<As1...>{});
   f3_helper(l2, t2, std::index_sequence_for<As2...>{});
 }  

int main()
 {
   auto l1 = [](auto && ... args)
    { f1(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

   auto l2 = [](auto && ... args)
    { f2(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

   f3(l1, l2, std::make_tuple(1, 2l, '3'), std::make_tuple('4', 5ull));
 }
```

Comment: In this case, how do I pass in the params to f1 and f2?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld - do you mean: to fix a precise set of types of arguments?

Comment: what I mean is when I call f3, I offer f1 and f2. I also need to pass in the params for f1 and f2. How do I do that?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: with `std::tuple` ? but unsure why you need extra parameter with template functor.

Comment: @Jarod42 how do I do that? What's the f3 function signature?

Comment: @max66: Or "directly": `f3([](auto&& args) { f1(decltype(args)(args)...); }, [](auto&& args) { f2(decltype(args)(args)...); });`

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: `template<class F1, class F2, class ... Ts1, class ...Ts2> void f3(F1, F2, std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>)`.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld - improved formatting; hope this helps.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes... maybe better with lambdas... so you can use `std::apply()` with tuples of arguments; good idea; thanks.

Comment: @max66 your answer looks great! "But the argument for f1() and f2() are the same? Or are two different sets?" They are two different sets. This is exactly what I am asking. I know how to do that if they are the same, I don't know how to do that if they are different. In your answer, can I just replace " std::apply(l1, t1);" with "f1(std::forward<decltype(t1)>(t1)...)"?

Comment: @max66  if I don't have std::apply how do I do that? Any idea?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld - "can I just replace " std::apply(l1, t1);" with "f1(std::forward<decltype(t1)>(t1)...)"?" - no, because `t1` is a `std::tuple` and `f1()` receive a variadic set of arguments.

Comment: @max66 well, in this case how do I do that without c++17?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld - " if I don't have std::apply how do I do that?" - through `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` (but C++14 is required; in C++11 you have to write a substitute but isn't really difficult); give me some minutes ans I prepare an example.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld - answer improved.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: And `f3([](){f1(1, 2l, '3');}, [](){f2('4', 5ull)});` seems simpler as interface.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it's simpler. But it's not generic. I have multiple clients. One wants to call f3 with f1(1, '2') and one wants to call with f1(1). Same for f2.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: How `f3(l1, l2, std::make_tuple(1, 2l, '3'), std::make_tuple('4', 5ull));` is more generic than `f3([](){f1(1, 2l, '3');}, [](){f2('4', 5ull)});` ? You might avoid some duplication if you have the argument tuple that you want to share between functions... Or if you have different set of argument in `f3`, my proposal doesn't fit...